# Two viewmodels with a lot of the same properties - how to optimize?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

In the name of keeping things DRY, I'd like to ask what the typical approach is when trying to avoid declaring duplicate properties.  I have two viewModels: set and folder.  Here they are:

Folder:

```
var folderViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.isHovering = ko.observable(false);
    self.showCheckbox = function () {
        self.isHovering(true);
    };
    self.hideCheckbox = function () {
        self.isHovering(false);
    };
    self.checkboxIsVisible = ko.computed(function () {
        return selectedItemsCount() > 0 || self.isHovering();
    }, self);
    self.softCheckboxIsVisible = ko.computed(function () {
        return selectedItemsCount() > 0 && self.isHovering() == false;
    }, self);
    self.canDrag = ko.computed(function () {
        if (selectedItemsCount() == 0 && !isAddingNewContent()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }, self);
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleSelected = function () {
        self.isSelected(!self.isSelected());
    };
    self.textSelected = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleTextSelected = function () {
        self.textSelected(!self.textSelected());
    };
    self.isSet = ko.observable(false);
    self.isDeleting = ko.observable(false);
    self.isNew = ko.observable(false);
    // If the folder hasn't been created yet, it won't have a folderId
    if (typeof self.folderId === 'undefined') {
        self.isNew(true);
    }
    self.isEditing = ko.observable(false).publishOn("IS_EDITING_CONTENT");
    // monitor for clicks 
    // temp title
    self.oldTitle = ko.observable();
};
```

Set:

```
var setViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    // Checkbox controls
    self.isHovering = ko.observable(false);
    self.showCheckbox = function () {
        self.isHovering(true);
    };
    self.hideCheckbox = function () {
        self.isHovering(false);
    };
    self.checkboxIsVisible = ko.computed(function () {
        return selectedItemsCount() > 0 || this.isHovering();
    }, self);
    self.softCheckboxIsVisible = ko.computed(function () {
        return selectedItemsCount() > 0 && this.isHovering() == false;
    }, self);

    self.canDrag = ko.computed(function () {
        if (selectedItemsCount() == 0 && !isAddingNewContent()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }, self);
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleSelected = function () {
        self.isSelected(!self.isSelected());
    };
    self.textSelected = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleTextSelected = function () {
        self.textSelected(!self.textSelected());
    };
    self.isSet = ko.observable(true);

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    self.isDeleting = ko.observable(false);
    self.isNew = ko.observable(false);
    // If the folder hasn't been created yet, it won't have a folderId
    if (typeof self.setId === 'undefined') {
        self.isNew(true);
    }
    self.isEditing = ko.observable(false).publishOn("IS_EDITING_CONTENT");
    // temp title
    self.oldTitle = ko.observable();

};
```

A lot of these properties are duplicated between the viewModels.  Should I just keep them as is, or is there a nice way to condense this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper method that both viewmodel constructors call to add all of the common properties...

```
var helper = function (self, data) {
    self.isHovering = ko.observable(false);
    // ...
    return self;
};
var setViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = helper(this, data);
    // extra stuff
};
var folderViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = helper(this, data);
    // extra stuff
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What about trying inheritance? You could program a prototype viewModel with the properties and functions that both (set and folder) have and then define new "classes" for setViewModel and folderViewModel that have the same prototype as viewModel, just added the properties and functions that only they have.

Introduction to inheritance in javascript can be found [here...](http://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance/)